# Tau Prolog nth0 nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, prolog, tau-prolog

I give error with work prolog
SWI-Prolog work ok.
Using Node js

```
const pl  = require('tau-prolog');
const session = pl.create();
require("tau-prolog/modules/promises.js")(pl);
require("tau-prolog/modules/lists.js")(pl);
require("tau-prolog/modules/random.js")(pl);
```

In lists have nth0/3 and nth0/4
but

```
nth(Board,X,Row):-
    write(X),
    nth0(X, Board, Row).
```

```
 const goal = `nth(0,[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],Row).`;
        console.log(goal);
        await session.promiseConsult("./backend/ch1.pl");
        await session.promiseQuery(goal);

        const data = await session.promiseAnswers(); 

        return [await data.next()];
```

I get error with nth0 , why? HELP Me please.. :(
Board is matrix

I trying other nth0 (self) , but not have enought time :(